# Oracle Database Multiple Instance

Tags: database, oracle, sid

Can anybody elaborate the architecture of Oracle database which have multiple instance? I want to create a multiple instance in my local oracle database.

Currently I assume that 1 SID = 1 database. is that correct?

Do i need to have different listener for each SID? or I just need 1 listener for every SID in my machine?

Answer (score 0):

Usually yes, 1 SID is 1 database with the exception of RAC (Real Application Cluster) where you can have multiple instances on different servers for the same database. In this case all the instances share the same database by accessing a SAN for exemple.

You don't need to have a separate listener for each instance on the same server, I listener is sufficient for multiple instance, it's a good practice to have the listener running on the higher version of oracle though.

You can have multiple instances on the same server using multiple oracle versions.